# Randomly spawn one by one object in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How do I generate objects one by one on a map, without them occupying the same space or overlapping on a HTML5 Canvas?

So, circle is randomly generated on screen and lasts few secs there, and then new circle generates. They can generate even before the first circle is "destroyed" but not at the same time.

This is what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/SamuraiFox/p9sDB/

```
<div id="circle" onclick="resize()"></div>
```

--> I need this animation to play when circle is spawned and it should play without onclick...so automatically.

Comment: This in not specific enough. You need to state an actual problem and tell us what you have tried and how that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/XcMMA/

[image]

**If you have an array of circle objects formed like this:**

```
var circles=[];

circles.push({
    x:x,
    y:y,
    radius:r,
    color:randomColor(),
    countdown:500+Math.random()*1000
});
```

**Then you can add new random, non-overlapping circles like this:**

```
var r=10+Math.random()*15;
var x=Math.random()*cw;
var y=Math.random()*ch;

// make sure new circle doesn't overlap any existing circles
while(true){
    var hit=0;
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
        var circle=circles[i];
        var dx=x-circle.x;
        var dy=y-circle.y;
        var rr=r+circle.radius;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<rr*rr){ hit++; }
    }
    // new circle doesn't overlap any other, so break
    if(hit==0){break;}
    x=Math.random()*cw;
    y=Math.random()*ch;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Jsfiddle example is excellent but has two problems(minor): 1. Circles are spawning almost out of the window and are half visible 2. I would prefer if there were no more than 3 circles spawned at the time.

Comment: You're welcome!  The positioning and circle-count are more your styling decisions.  So feel free to take the example I've provided here and modify it for your needs.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: heh thanks...it's just that I don't know how to change positioning...anyways,thanks :)

Comment: Ok, here's an updated fiddle with 3 circles that keep away from the edge:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/XcMMA/  Notice the change in calculating the x & y values which now take into account the circle radius.  Cheers!

Comment: Know how to implement this anim instead of just disappearing?
http://jsfiddle.net/SamuraiFox/p9sDB/

Comment: See my example code which already has an animation loop.  Inside, the loop you could (1) reduce the circle radius or (2) reduce the circle opacity until it "fades away".  Really it's all your design decision.  Check out the code and have fun!

Comment: Did you click the circle to see the animation? http://jsfiddle.net/SamuraiFox/p9sDB/
Because I would like that animation to start playing immediately after the circle is spawned. And if you click on the circle before the animation is over that the circle plays another animation that I will implement.

Comment: The automatic moderator is getting anxious about the quantity of our additional comments.  Perhaps open another question...